# I can't start activity from listview.getSelectedItemPosition()

Tags: android, listview

I have accurately defined activities but I cant start activity from lview1.getSelectedItemPosition(). When I clicked listview item nothing happened. Eclipse didn't throw an error. What is missing?

I haven't paste import lines

```
package com.batteryproject;

public class Anamenu extends Activity
{

private String lview_arr[]={"Şarj Azaldı Alarmı","Şarj Doldu Alarmı","Hırsız Alarmı"};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.anamenu);

final ListView lview1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
lview1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lview_arr));
//lview1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
lview1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    int selected=lview1.getSelectedItemPosition();
    switch(selected){

    case 0:
    Intent intent=new Intent("com.batteryproject.ALTMENU1");
    startActivity(intent);
    break;

    case 1 :
    Intent intent2=new Intent("com.batteryproject.ALTMENU2");
    startActivity(intent2);
    break;

    case 2 :
    Intent intent3=new Intent("com.batteryproject.ALTMENU3");
    startActivity(intent3);
    break;

    }
}
});
}}
```

Comment: Change your switch statement to use "position" instead of "selected". getSelectedItemPosition() does not do what you are expecting it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `getSelectedItemPosition()` to `position`